# Redirect user to Login page with message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to display a message to a user if he or she is **not** registered or signed up before accessing a page

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult LearningTopics()
{

}
```

As it is now the user is directed to the login page.

How can I determine as to whether the user was directed to the Login page because of the [Authorize] attribute so that I can display a message like 'Please login to access learner topics.'

Comment: I think your workflow is a little flawed.  Just because the user isn't authenticated (and gets redirected) doesn't mean the user needs to register.  Perhaps the user just needs to login.  Or register.  Which is typically why the login page has a link to register on ("new user?  Register here" type of thing).

Comment: I agree with @ThomasStringer - Also, you need to rethink how you are authenticated the user and you need to keep track of this status through the life cycle of the users session.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I perhaps worded it a bit incorrectly. I mean not logged in or regustered. The user would need to log in or reguster to access the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the [Return URL Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.returnurlparameter(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions.ReturnUrlParameter) on the page in either the server code or the view code to determine if the page was redirected or not.

For example, if your return URL parameter was `returnUrl` then in the log in route you could do

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) { 
    // add a message "Please register" to the view.
}
```